# Read multiple CSVs from same file into separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file that really contains 2 separate CSVs split by a title line for each. The number of lines in the Polymerase Stats section can be anywhere between 1 and 8 and the number of lines in the CCS Stats section does not technically have a limit but will never exceed 50.

My current solution is to enumerate the input file, look for the occurrence of "CCS Stats", and use that line number to skip rows/set the number of rows to read since the number of title rows is constant. This works but ideally I'd like to accomplish this all with pandas.

Simplified CSV Example:

```
RUNID: TEST_RUN
Polymerase Stats:
Cell,Project,Name,Bases,Reads
A01,Proj1,Cell_1,17438371,2836501
B01,Proj1,Cell_2,19327981,3789533
C01,Proj2,Cell_3,14935525,1897239
CCS Stats:
Cell,Project,Name,CCS_Bases,CCS_Reads,MedQ
A01,Proj1,Sample_1,5473982,123678,31
B01,Proj1,Sample_2,5834094,738491,32
B01,Proj1,Sample_3,5834094,738491,31
C01,Proj2,Sample_4,4378978,453216,31
```

Current Solution:

```
with open("run_stats.csv") as f:
    for num, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if "CCS Stats" in line:
            csv_split=num
df_runstats_poly = pd.read_csv("run_stats.csv", skiprows=2, nrows=csv_split-3)
df_runstats_ccs = pd.read_csv("run_stats.csv", skiprows=csv_split)
```

Comment: Do you really need another solution? Pandas alone is not a good solution. Your solution looks good.

Comment: @Corralien No, I don't absolutely need one but was hoping pandas had some sort of read option that could split a csv on a pattern during the read. Wasn't positive anything like that existed and couldn't find anything so I figured I'd ask. Thank you for the response!